# Build successful but not executing tagged junit test cases using gradle command

Tags: gradle, junit, tags

I'm using below gradle command to run test cases :-
./gradlew  integrationTest -Ptag=regression

Comment: maybe try to share build.gradle file ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.